# after adding elements through button why clicking on list items will not change the heading?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple application. There is a list, clicking on an item in the list will update the header to match the text of the list item. There is also a button to add new items to the list.

Here is my code

```js
var counter = 1;
var MyList = document.querySelector("#mylist"); // mylist is id of ul
var heading = document.querySelector("#heading"); // heading is id of header
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#mylist li");

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", changeHead);
}

function changeHead() {
  heading.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addRecord);

function addRecord() {
  MyList.innerHTML += "<li>something New " + counter + "</li>";
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hii,Bhushan</h1> <button class="btn">Add New</button>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>bhushan dhage</li>
  <li>vishal Ambhore</li>
  <li>Ravi kauthale</li>
  <li>manik jadhav</li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on list items seems to work correctly but when I add a new list item and click on it the header does not update. Do you know why this is the case?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think you need to read my first comment's link again...

Comment: I think when you add a new `li` you should run the for loop again because the event is no longer attached to the new `li` (and I guess the old ones too for some reason?)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you only add your `eventListener` once, you have to add it to the new item each time you add one.

If I were you rather than using `innerHTML` I would use `createElement` and then append your new element to the list. This has the added advantage of being able to add your eventListener to the new `li` while you're making it.

> In an [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) document, the **`document.createElement()`** method creates the HTML element specified by `tagName`, or an [`HTMLUnknownElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) if `tagName` isn't recognized.

Here is the code, the only changes are in the `addRecord` function

```js
var counter = 1;
var MyList = document.querySelector("#mylist"); // mylist is id of ul
var heading = document.querySelector("#heading"); // heading is id of header
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#mylist li");

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list[i].addEventListener("click", changeHead);
}

function changeHead() {
  heading.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addRecord);

function addRecord() {
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  var text = document.createTextNode("something New " + counter);
  listItem.appendChild(text)
  listItem.addEventListener("click", changeHead);
  MyList.appendChild(listItem);
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hii,Bhushan</h1> <button class="btn">Add New</button>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>bhushan dhage</li>
  <li>vishal Ambhore</li>
  <li>Ravi kauthale</li>
  <li>manik jadhav</li>
</ul>
```

I hope you find this helpful if anything is confusing feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

i did a simple change in your code, might help you

```js
var counter = 1;
var MyList = document.querySelector("#mylist"); // mylist is id of ul
var heading = document.querySelector("#heading"); // heading is id of header
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#mylist li");

MyList.onclick = function(e) {
  heading.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
}

btn.addEventListener("click", addRecord);

function addRecord() {
  MyList.innerHTML += "<li>something New " + counter + "</li>";
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Hii,Bhushan</h1> <button class="btn">Add New</button>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>bhushan dhage</li>
  <li>vishal Ambhore</li>
  <li>Ravi kauthale</li>
  <li>manik jadhav</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: could u please explain me e.target part.

Comment: e is your event in this case `onclick`, `e.target` will return the element that triggered the event, in this case its `<li>` from mylist as i bind click event on `<ul id='mylist'>`, once you get element you can get its text with innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you i removed unnecesary functions created an li element rather than changing myList innerHtml. also when new li created a event listener is added to it.

```
    let counter = 1;

    myList.forEach(function(element) {
        addListener(element);
      });


    function addListener(element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function() {
            heading.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        });
    }

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let newLi = document.createElement("LI");
        newLi.innerHTML= "Something New" + counter;
        addListener(newLi);
        counter ++;

        MyList.appendChild(newLi);
    });
```